# В цикле вместо добавления значений в массив идет перезапись

Tags: массивы, javascript, циклы

Функция осуществляет вывод данных для построения диаграммы ганта, корневые задачи записываются нормально, а вот вложенные не хотят, если ставлю запись подзадач не за последним элементом массива в на его место то все вложенные задачи он перезаписывает сюда в одну запись оставляя одну последнего уровня вложенности (если она есть).

Собственно вроде все просто но что я забыл не могу понять. Нужно чтобы в массив дальше записывались данные так:

```
задача 1
 - подзадача
 - подзадача 2
   - подзадача подзадачи
задача 2
```

Код функции:

```
ogTasks.drawGantt = function() {
    var taskslist = {data:[]};
    // ОБХОДИМ ПРОЕКТЫ И С КАЖДОГО ЗАПИСЫВАЕМ ДАННЫЕ
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Groups.length; i++){
        var group = this.Groups[i];
        var maxvalue = this.Groups.length;
        taskslist.data[i] = {...};

        // ВНУТРИ КАЖДОГО ПРОЕКТА ИЩЕМ ЗАДАЧИ И ДЛЯ КАЖДОЙ ВЫВОДИМ ДАННЫЕ
        for (var k = 0; k < group.group_tasks.length; k++){
            var task = group.group_tasks[k];
            taskslist.data[maxvalue+k] = {...};

            // ВНУТРИ ЗАДАНИЯ ИЩЕМ И ВЫВОДИМ ПОДЗАДАЧИ
            if (task.subtasks && task.subtasks.length > 0) {
                var stvalue = maxvalue+k;
                for (var x=0; x < task.subtasks.length; x++) {
                    var subt = task.subtasks[i];

                    taskslist.data[stvalue+x] = {...};

                    // ВНУТРИ ПОДЗАДАЧИ ИЩЕМ И ВЫВОДИМ ОЧЕРЕДНУЮ ВЛОЖЕННОСТЬ
                    if (subt.subtasks && subt.subtasks.length > 0) {
                        var sbtvalue = stvalue+x;
                        for (var j=0; j < subt.subtasks.length; j++) {
                            taskslist.data[sbtvalue+j] = {...};
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return taskslist;
}
```

Comment: @kils Солидарен с @Volt. У вас я вижу проблема с реализацией, а не с пониманием бизнес-логики. В чем конкретно проблема? Объясните оперируя терминами javascript - объект, массив, функция и т.д. А то диаграммы Ганта в 13 часов утра осваивать как-то не хочется.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/14981/alvoro убрал весь мусор из функции. Суть такая: Скрипт ищет вложенные элементы внутри текущего максимально углубляясь на 2 уровня вложенности и записывает все найденные элементы в массив. Что нужно переписывать и что сейчас можно сделать много короче понятно, но даже сейчас она нормально не работает.

Заходим в цикл, берем первый объект, записываем данные и смотрим его на дочек, затем в каждой дочке смотрим есть ли внучки. После перебора всех дочек и внучек и их записи переходим к следующему объекту.

Comment: @kils, почему это не сделать нормальной человеческой рекурсией, вместо четырех циклов с головоломным индексом?

Comment: @Volt сперва я сделал вывод только корневых элементов, потом и начал делать рекурсию, через функцию с вызовом самой себя, но там возникла проблема с пустыми элементами и я решил для начала сделать на циклах, а уже потом когда все пойму сделать рекурсию, но как видите и здесь не могу справиться.

Comment: Входные данные:

this.Groups = [{group_tasks: [...]}, {group_tasks: [...]}, {group_tasks: [...]},{group_tasks: [...]}, ....];
this.Groups[i].group_tasks = [{subtasks: [...]}, {subtasks: [...]}, {subtasks: [...]}, {subtasks: [...]}, ...];
this.Groups[i].group_tasks[k].subtasks = [{subsub: [вот тут уже нас не интерсисует что], ....}];

Задача:
Получить объект taskslist со свойcтвом data типа:
[grop_tasks1, grop_tasks3, ... ,grop_tasksN, subtasks1, subtasks2, ... ,subtasksN, subsub1, subsub2, ... subsubN];


Я прав?

Comment: @alvoro если не считать нескольких неточностей то да, за исключением того, что объект taskslist со свойcтвом data типа: [grop_tasks1, grop_tasks3, subtasks1, subtasks2, subsub1, subsub2, ... subsubN ... ,subtasksN, ... ,grop_tasksN];

то есть дочка должна идти сразу после родителя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не тестировал, но, по идее, должно работать.

```
function parse (groups) {
  var result = [];
  groups.forEach (function (group_tasks) {
    //Исходим из того, что group_tasks всегда Array
    result.push(group_tasks);
    group_tasks.forEach(function (subtasks) {
      //Исходим из того, что subtasks всегда Array
      result.push(subtasks);
      subtasks.forEach(function (subsub) {
        //Исходим из того, что subsub всегда Array
        result.push(sudsud);
      });
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Или как-то так:

```
function parse (groups) {
  var result = [];
  groups.forEach (function (group_tasks) {
    //Исходим из того, что group_tasks всегда Array
    result.push(group_tasks);
    group_tasks.group_tasks.forEach(function (subtasks) {
      //Исходим из того, что subtasks всегда Array
      result.push(subtasks);
      subtasks.subtasks.forEach(function (subsub) {
        //Исходим из того, что subsub всегда Array
        result.push(sudsud.subsub);
      });
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Метод массива forEach в качестве второго параметра принимает контекст вызова callback-а. Учтите это, если захотите сделать parse методом какого объекта.

Comment: смысл я понял, буду пробовать. Спасибо